# DB2 The Specified I/O device is not ready

Tags: db2, database-backups, db2-luw

When I try to restore a database I get the following error:

> SQL0976N  The specified I/O device is not ready.  SQLSTATE=57021

I have checked my hard disk, it's working fine, also checked  DB2 version of source database and target database, both are same version (10.1FP4)

I have tried to restore this database on another server but the same error occurs.

Comment: Look for more details in the DB2 diagnostics file (example db2diag.log ), to which which device or mount point is giving the issue. Also look in the operating system message log (e.g. For MS Windows, the event viewer) .

Comment: [link] (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7ZoYDQ7A9TUdGg2MU1xYTluaEU) Please see attached log file.